# Vapors from washing machine stinking the garage and kitchen

Tags: drain-waste-vent

This shows that there is a trap in the washing machine drain[How do I hook up a washing machine drain line to this box?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/43843/how-do-i-hook-up-a-washing-machine-drain-line-to-this-box/94866#94866). How do I clean this?  Other traps under sinks have threaded connectors so I can extricate crap. And somehow my drain hose is stuck in the box as gentle tugging will not disconnect it;  is there a clip inside that somehow grips it?  Coz' suddenly after 10 years, our Maytag front load washer is eschewing vapors into the garage and even into the kitchen sink and it seems needs a clean-out.

Comment: So, smell is coming out of the trap? How is the smell getting to the garage and/or kitchen sink? (I don't associate washing machine drainwater with bad smells, even when aged gracefully...)

Comment: After reading this <http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/16444/do-i-need-a-vent-for-extending-a-drain-to-a-new-bathroom-addition> I'm wondering if our new upstairs master bath remodel 2 years ago tweaked something; the counter sinks are a few inches higher; one drains normally and one drains very slowly until reaching 4 " depth whence it is slirpped up!  Also the tub was replaced by a shower and drain moved. But what plugs a vent stack?

Comment: After cogitating the when and where, here's my explanation:  kitchen --2 drains, one to the garberator and one to the side sink, both are connected to the to of the p-trap.  When the side sink is emptied it pushes air into the p-trap forcing it to empty and causing back flow of stink into the gaburator.  I need a sign "health hazard" for my kitchen!                For the garage, I filled the laundry tub and the vapors dissipated ; so the washing water flow is siphoning the p-trap;  another sign "keep tub full"

Answer (score 1):

If it isn't spraying water, it doesn't need a clean-out. More likely your vent stack needs to be cleaned out.

Answer (score 0):

Neighbors suggested Tide washing Machine Cleanser; after 2 cycles the sewer smell is gone; of course we now know why, where, and when we get gassed   Nonanoic acid, sulfophenyl ester http://www.pesticideinfo.org/Detail_Chemical.jsp?Rec_Id=PC36022 smells noxious, irritates the eyes but does the job making sewer gas sweeter.

Answer (score 0):

Sequel
  After a few days the stench returned.  Nothing focuses like a spousal rebuke; I vaguely recollected that smell from 50 years ago-- the root cellar potato bin in spring. Aha! An aggregation of veggies -- where is this "clean-out" on this 1987 house?  Outside the kitchen stucco wall is a 7 cm pipe plastered in, with a square nut cap about 30 cm off the ground. A non-metric nut!  Dig out that 1 1\4 " flat wrench; apply some newtons; she won't budge!  A neighbor had died 5 years ago and the heirs gave me his pipe wrench--a use for it! Use joules on the pipe wrench and the nut loosens without busting any stucco.  I filled the 2 basins to the brim; dissolved 100 g of nonanoic acid sulfophenyl ester in each , opened the drains and turned on the garberator, with a 4 l bucket under the clean-out;  the surfactant foamed and frothed and spat a big doggy bag of $!$&&. OK then do that agin! Still a bit more .  Now we have sweet smelling sewers .

Comment: Hello. You should merge your two accounts as [shown here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), so you can get credit for all your contributions.